# Storing a lambda expression in a variable removes inline optimization

Tags: kotlin, kotlin1.4

I am looking into optimizing the size of the call stack by using inline functions.

If you execute the following code:

```
inline fun function2( action: () -> Unit) {
 action()
}

fun function1() {

 function2{ printCurrentStack() }
}

fun printCurrentStack() {
 RuntimeException().printStackTrace()
}

fun main() {
 function1()
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.printCurrentStack(PrimeNumbers.kt:17)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt$function1$1.invoke(PrimeNumbers.kt:13)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt$function1$1.invoke(PrimeNumbers.kt)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.function2(PrimeNumbers.kt:8)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.function1(PrimeNumbers.kt:13)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt:21)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt)
```

So, in this case, the stack has 7 elements.

- Calling `main`
- Calling `function1`
- Calling `function2`
- 2 calls for the lambda expression
- Calling `printCurrentStack`
- Calling `printStackTrace`

Now, if I mark `function2` as inline and I execute the code, I get the following output:

```
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.printCurrentStack(PrimeNumbers.kt:17)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.function1(PrimeNumbers.kt:13)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt:21)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt)
```

This seems to work great, the size of the call stack is reduced by 3.
However, if I update `function1` to store the lambda in a variable before sending it to `function2`:

```
fun function1() {
 val lambda = { printCurrentStack() }
 function2(lambda)
}
```

The output changes to this:

```
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.printCurrentStack(PrimeNumbers.kt:15)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt$function1$lambda$1.invoke(PrimeNumbers.kt:10)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt$function1$lambda$1.invoke(PrimeNumbers.kt)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.function1(PrimeNumbers.kt:21)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt:19)
at com.kotlin.playground.functional.PrimeNumbersKt.main(PrimeNumbers.kt)
```

The size of the call stack goes from 4 to 6 although `function2` is still marked as an `inline` function.

It seems that the lambda calls cannot be inlined if the lambda is stored in a variable.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Storing it in a variable creates a functional object for the lambda so it can be stored. It's the object that the variable is pointing to in memory.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the answer. So, isn't that functional object immutable? If it is, then what is stopping kotlin from being able to copy the lambda and inline it?

Comment: By assigning it to a variable, you are explicitly telling the compiler to assign it to a variable. Whether the JVM inlines it at runtime is another matter. It may very well do that, but I'm not an expert.